# Install old version of Wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux, winetricks

Recording to this page https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=9597&iTestingId=56155, I should install older version of wine (max. 20041019), in order to run D2GS (game server).

Can anyone help me with that?

As I've heard, the easiest way is with PlayOnLinux, but I'm looking for a direct way of installation.

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe what isn't working exactly with the version of wine which comes in the version of Ubuntu you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the information on that page that mentions a wine version from 2004 is extremely old (over 10 years old). The compatibility box at the top of the page suggests it works fine on the latest versions of wine.

If you are having a problem running it on the current version of wine in Ubuntu, the best thing to do would be to file a bug report with any crash details and with a description of the problem.

Comment: I actually already tried with the latest version, it didn't worked, and then found the page. And lastly, I've found this page: http://pliusinfo.blogspot.com/2012/04/howto-install-and-run-d2gs-under-linux.html, and he has been successfully installed it with wine from 2002 (Wine-20021007.tar.gz). Do you know from where I can download it? Thanks!

Comment: Versions of wine source are available on the wine site. You will have to compile it yourself, and it may not even compile on the latest Ubuntu. That is an even older version of wine than the comment on the page suggest though. Again, you should state what exactly doesn't work, and report a bug. Old versions of wine may have security holes that have long since been fixed, along with many other bugs.

Comment: I've found it - http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/OldFiles/Wine-20021125-i386-1.tgz/download, but it says i386. What version of Ubuntu should I use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adambots-live/files/debian-wine/wine-20041019/) First run `apt-get install build-essential`.
This will provide you necessary development tools from respective repositary and which are not included in default Ubuntu system.

[2] Download the **wine_0.0.20041019-1.3.tar.gz** from [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adambots-live/files/debian-wine/wine-20041019/)

and extract the file.

[3] Open terminal and enter the following commands:

```
$cd wine-20041019

$./configure
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had a mistake in my topic. It will actually work with version from 2002, not from 2004, which I'm not sure that would work with the latest Ubuntu. But I'll try now and I'll let you know.